# Google maps on Android in the sunlight

Tags: android, google-maps, brightness

I am developing an application in Android with a map based UI. 
The main use of the app is on the water, in direct sunlight.

1. Are there good guidelines/examples for developing such UI (for best sunlight readability)
2. Are there any built in features or things I can do, specifically in Google maps or other Android maps API, to make the UI better in sunlight conditions?

Comment: I think its more of a UI/UX problem than a coding problem.

Comment: @KNeerajLal it is a mix of both in my view but I thought it is more related to coding. I am checking for answer in ux forums as well though.

Comment: The best option is to set the brightness of the screen to maximum. But this will lead to serious battery issues.

Comment: What you want to do can be achieved through [Custom Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), unfortunately, Google Maps for Android does not support it  and it is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite#supported_api_features). It says, "The Google Maps Android API does not support custom styles.".